# Access azure file from hadoop

Tags: hadoop, azure-storage-files

I am able to access azure storage blobs from hadoop by using the folowing command

wasb[s]://@.blob.core.windows.net/

But i am not able to access Azure file. Can anyone suggest how to access azure storage files from Hadoop just like blobs ?

Comment: You need to configure a separate file system, no?

Comment: From the documentation below it looks like only blob storage support with the HDinsight
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#use-additional-storage-accounts

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

> HDInsight can use a blob container in Azure Storage as the default
>   file system for the cluster. Through a Hadoop distributed file system
>   (HDFS) interface, the full set of components in HDInsight can operate
>   directly on structured or unstructured data stored as blobs.

From the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#hdinsight-storage-architecture) , `HDinsight` only supports Azure Blob Storage.
File Storage is not supported currently.